# Block methods in interface for users usage

Tags: java, methods, interface

Imagine, I would like to create the following (simplified) structure:

```java
    public interface IAlgorithm {
        public int execute(int input);
        public int execute(int input, int input2);
        public int execute(int input, int input2, double input3);
        // Further execute(...)-definitions
    }
```

We have different classes, which implements this interface:

```java
    public class CalcSquare implements IAlgorithm {
        public int execute(int input) {
            return input * input;
        }
        public int execute(int input, int input2) { return -1; }
        public int execute(int input, int input2, double input3) { return -1; }
    }
```

```java
    public class CalcMultiplication implements IAlgorithm {
        public int execute(int input) { return -1; }
        public int execute(int input, int input2) {
            return input * input2;
        }
        public int execute(int input, int input2, double input3) { return -1; }
    }
```

```java
    public class CalcWith3Parameters implements IAlgorithm {
        public int execute(int input) { return -1; }
        public int execute(int input, int input2) { return -1; }
        public int execute(int input, int input2, double input3) { return doSomething(input, input2, input3); }
    }
```

In other words: the interface defines one method with different combinations of parameters. If a user wants to instantiate a specific class, e.g. CalcMultiplication, he can do something like this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IAlgorithm mult = new CalcMultiplication();
        int result m = mult.execute(1, 2);
    }
```

Now, in an IDE (e.g. Eclipse) we can press Ctrl and Space after "mult." to show the possibilities of the object "mult". It will show all 3 execute()-Methods, even two of them will not make sense for this class.

It does not make sense to show at "CalcSquare" the second and third method.
It does not make sense to show at "CalcMultiplication" the first and third method.
It does not make sense to show at "CalcWith3Parameters" the first and second method.

My question: Is there any possibility, e.g. via Annotations, to "block" not "allowed" methods in these three classes, but to use one and the same IAlgorithm-interface to handle different "IAlgorithm"-objects? A user should just see a specific set of execute()-methods on a concrete instantiated object. I would like to avoid three different interfaces with just one execute()-definition.

Thanks 
Alex

Comment: The best idea that I can come up with at first is to throw UnsupportedOperationException, though in this case method still can be called

Comment: And also I think there is a problem with how you use polymorphism. As I understand you want to have set of common methods in interface and this methods will do different things depending on implementation. Though actually different implementions should do the same thing but in different ways.

Comment: Well, of course the algorithms above do not the same, each algorithm should be different, and therefore I need different execute()-methods with different parameters (number of params and type of params)

Comment: That's not how interfaces should be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only put in the interface operations that are polymorphic, and are intended for multiple implementations with the same signature. Use UnsupportedOperationException only if most implementations support the signature. If it is logically the same operation with different signatures, think about changing the design to make it the same signature for all, for example passing the parameters in constructors or in builder objects.

Comment: I think your approach to pass the parameters via the contructor helped to get rid of a few Interfaces and bind the correct parameters to the corresponding algorithm classes. Sometimes, if you work to long at a specific part of code, you get blind of finding a simple solution. Thx.